# Question related to the diameter of each subdivision of a triangle

Tags: geometry, analysis

Given a triangle $\triangle_0$, building another triangle with the midpoints of each edge it generates $4$ triangles, I will name them $\triangle_1$,$\triangle_2$,$\triangle_3$ and $\triangle_4$.

I cannot prove rigorously that  $d(\triangle_i)=\frac{d(\triangle_0)}{2}$ $\forall i=1,2,3,4$
 Being $d(\triangle_i)=\sup\{\lvert| x-y \rvert|: x,y\in \triangle _i\}$ the diameter of the triangle. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that the triangles are similar with scale factor $ \frac{1}{2}$.

Let $ T$ be the transformation that maps $\Delta$ to $\Delta_1$.
Then $\sup \{ || x - y || : x, y \in \Delta \}  = 2 \sup \{ ||T(x) - T(y)|| : T(x), T(y) \in \Delta_i \}$, so $d( \Delta ) =  2 d ( \Delta_1)$.

Comment: I did that but I don't know how to continue

Comment: @JackTalion I've added more details. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck because I don't understand the step that you go from $d(\triangle)$ and then come up with the idea of the transformation between every triangle and why is true.

Comment: Do you agree that $ || x - y || = 2 || T(x) - T(y) ||$?

Comment: How could I define such transformation? Because I cannot understand how with only 1 variable i can define it? Thanks in advance.